# Form Minimize to another form

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012

i am not sure whether my question is correct or if its a duplicate Question. I have a main form with buttons that open form 2 ,3 and 4 . What i want is that when form 2 is minimized i want to show the minimized form 2 at the bottom of the main form instead of the windows taskbar. Any hints?? What are the events?

Comment: Are you talking about the MDI concept.??? I mean these forms will be opened in one single form and if you are minimizing one of them, then it will be minimized under the main form (MDI form). Please confirm your question and give little more details. So that it will help to solve the problem. :)

Comment: Yes Thats what i meant ! i am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Can you please tell me, how exactly are you proceeding. I mean, can you share your code or something..??

Comment: For example 1 main form ,3 buttons , each button open different blank forms. When one of the blank form gets minimize it minimize to the main form. That is what i am proceeding with. And for coding i dont know where to do start. I only know a form has properties to disable maximize .